# Eclipse breakpoint in single / one line lambda?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, lambda, java-8

How can I set a breakpoint in a single line lambda?

e.g. I'd like the (eclipse) debugger to halt, when `outer.doSth(event)` is called:

```
observable.addCallback(event-> outer.doSth(event));
```

Comment: Sadly there is no way to do it without formating

Comment: An alternative is to put breakpoint inside the `doSth` method.

Comment: Well, you can just set a breakpoint at the line containing the lambda expression, but have to live with the fact that execution will stop at both points, before invoking `addCallback` and before invoking `doSth`. This isn’t different to any other nesting of expressions. If you want to differentiate, insert line breaks…

Comment: @Holger Well in intellij you can.

Comment: This is now open as [bug 486264](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=486264) on the eclipse bugzilla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

If you refactor it like this:

```
observable.addCallback(event-> {
    return outer.doSth(event);
});
```

you can.

Comment: There is no need to turn the lambda expression into the verbose syntax. It will also work using `event-> outer.doSth(event)` if you insert a line break after the `->`.

Answer (score 2):

Well this answer is not for eclipse, but in `intellij` you can (15.x)

[image]

You have an option to set a break point either at the line (which is the first option in the image), or at the first lambda or at second one. And so on.

Comment: How do you trigger that option?

Comment: Just click on  that line (adjacent to place where line  number is written)

Comment: I'm using android studio and I was hoping that such a feature would have made its way through to AS from intelliJ but alas... I still get a breakpoint for the entire line. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Oh. I am not sure. But I think it should be possible in adroid studio as well.

Comment: Scrap my previous comment. I tried to click a little further to the right to set a breakpoint and I got the prompt that breaks down the lambda expression!

Comment: I've been experimenting with this for the last 10 minutes now, and it seems that every now and then AS doesn't trigger the lambda prompt and simply adds a regular breakpoint. The workaround that I found was to click on the lambda symbol with the upwards arrow next to it that takes you to the responsible interface and then navigate back to the lambda expression. If I try to set the breakpoint after that, it's always the lambda prompt.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse 4.14.0 when I set a breakpoint into a lambda it works automatically correct and I am able to debug the lambda expression. But be aware that Eclipse also stops at the breakpoint at the "line" itself (that's before the stream operation is executed, since it's lazy):

[image: Breakpoint set as usual]

And here you see that I am able to see the value of the `group` variable:

[image]

So you don't have to reformat your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just making [@Holger 's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34875947/447426) an answer:

It is enough to break line after `->`

```
observable.addCallback(event-> 
          outer.doSth(event) //line break works here!
);
```